# Invalid characters in hostname

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Steps I am doing while getting this error is:
**All steps are performed in Gen2 **

- Reading csv file using spark.
- filtering for not null values for a particular column.
- Joining two DataFrame on 3 condition.
- [image].

Comment: which databricks are you using azure, aws or community? also can you provide the code that you are trying?